# Graph API - get JSON data without "paging" key

Tags: facebook, json, paging

I'm getting facebook data using graph api, adding fields in string and get JSON result.

Example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=music
```

But JSON returned contains a "paging" key and I do not I want this key.

```
{ "music":{
  "data":[
     {
        "name":"",
        "category":"",
        "id":"",
        "created_time":""
     },
     {
        "name":"",
        "category":"",
        "id":"",
        "created_time":""
     }
  ],
  "paging":{
     "next":"https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=music&method=GET&metadata=true&format=json&callback=___GraphExplorerAsyncCallback___&access_token=...&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=..."
  }}}
```

***EDITED:***

I'm using Java API (restfb.com) to get JSON.

The command in java is:

```
FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient("ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE");
JsonObject rMusic = client.fetchObject("ID_HERE", JsonObject.class, Parameter.with("fields", "id,name,religion,birthday,music"));
```

How do I avoid it or remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon the edit to the question above, here's a new answer.

The Rest API is **deprecated**.  You should upgrade your app to use the Graph API as this is the one being supported.

Also, if you see a property you don't like, you don't have to access it.  Remember, there's no law in coding that you have to look at every property in your scripts.

Comment: This is on the Graph API, not the Rest API.

Comment: "RestFB is a simple and flexible Facebook Graph API and Old REST API client written in Java". This API also implements graph api.I'm saving the JSON in the database, so do not want to save unnecessary data.

Comment: The write something called a DTO (Data Transformation Object) and only copy the fields you want to copy.  Then serialize that object to store as a string value in your datastore.

Comment: In graph API not is possible hide this key?

Comment: No, just use a DTO dude.  It's your only hope.  The amount of time it's taken you to ask further questions on this is the same amount of time it took for me to write a DTO.  They are very simple.

Comment: I solved removing paging key using com.restfb.json.JsonObject

Comment: Like I said, you just need to ignore it.  As you just did with the com.restfb.json.JsonObjec

Comment: Yes. I iterate for each key and check if has "paging" key, removing if exist. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you have your Javascript object built from the JSON, just pay attention to the array of data: result.music.data

And forget about the paging property: result.music.paging

Remember, there's no law in coding that you have to look at every property in your scripts.